# Open-source English-French Dictionary

Tags: resource-request, dictionary, electronic-resources, english, french

I'm looking for an English to French dictionary in a plain text file (.txt for example).

I already found some dictionaries but a lot of definitions are wrong or incomplete:

- know; savons, sache, connais, su, connaissons, savent;
- story; fabliau, étage;
- government; gouvernement.

Preferably, I'd like an open source file. Do you know where I could find such files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finding such a dictionary in open-source format is unlikely, due to the labor-intensive nature of composing dictionaries.

Your two best bets are probably:

1. Wiktionary. You can [download the entire Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Help:FAQ#Downloading_Wiktionary). Depending on your precise needs, and scripting skills, you may be able to coerce it into a usable format for your needs.
2. Any sufficiently old dictionary will be in the Public Domain by now, and you may be able to find text, or transcribe it using OCR software. Any such dictionary will be many decades old, perhaps more than a hundred years old, which may render the available definitions less useful, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [this list](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/User:Matthias_Buchmeier/en-fr-a) generated by a Wiktionary user from the data at the website’s translation tables. There’s a page for each letter, but it shouldn’t be too hard to put them all together.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which ones you tried already. This is the one I know:
[dict.cc](https://enfr.dict.cc/)